# Asp.Net(C#) Jquery Ajax with WebMethod In Public Method Call

Tags: asp.net, jquery

**Aspx Page:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $("#btnn").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "TestPage.aspx/emp",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

**CodeBehind:**

```
public void grdload()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = GetEmployee("Select * from Employee");
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

[WebMethod]
    public static void emp()
    {
        TestPage re = new TestPage();
        re.grdload();
    }
```

I Can't Gridview Data Load ? How To Make GridView Data Load?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `WebMethod`s like that in ASP.NET is meant to return a JSON dataset that you can parse through Javascript, not reload controls.

You should look in to using the ASP.NET AJAX toolkit and getting the `ScriptManager` and `UpdatePanel` on your page and using regular .NET code to update your `GridView`.

Comment: I Don't Want Scriptmanager, Json Data With How To Make GridView Data Load ? Please Help...

Comment: You can't load a server-side control with client-side scripting (using JSON) without either ScriptManager/UpdatePanel or a post-back. It's that simple. Your other option would be to have your WebMethod return the HTML of the GridView and then use jQuery to dump the HTML on to the page.

Comment: how its make "WebMethod return the HTML of the GridView and then use jQuery to dump the HTML on to the page"; im sorry, im junior developer :)

Answer (score 1):

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interact with the page in a WebMethod.

You should use an UpdatePanel instead.

Comment: Man...you're stealing all my thunder this morning. :-P